# HTTPConnectionPool redirect not working

Tags: python, redirect

Assume this page "www.test.com/redirecttest" redirects to another page "www.google.com"

The below code is not redirecting to google page but returns only 404 status for the test.com page.  All browsers work fine in redirecting the page.

How to get the response from the redirected page in python for HTTPConnectionPool?

```
firstPool = HTTPConnectionPool(firstServerURL, maxsize=10, retries =10)

res = firstPool.request("GET", "http://www.test.com/redirecttest",assert_same_host=False,redirect=True)
```

If I remove `assert_same_host=False` it returns error

> Tried to open a foreign host with url: http://www.google.com.

So I have added `assert_same_host=False` to avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

a HTTPConnectionPool is a pool for connections to "one specific host". If you redirect the request to another host, you are "leaving" this specific host. So without `assert_same_hos=False`, you will get a `HostChangedError`Exception as descripbed in the documentation: http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/pools.html#api

Comment: The documentation says "When False, you can use the pool on an HTTP proxy and request foreign hosts." I'm not getting forwarded to the foreign host with false. Its not returning the exception thats good but I'm expecting to reach the redirected URL.

Comment: The URL is broken. https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.connectionpool.html might be a fitting replacement.